# ChartJSNodeCanvas plugin chartjs-plugin-annotation creates error: HTMLCanvasElement is not defined

Tags: node.js, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-annotation

I want to create my chart as png on the server.
The X axe is based on time, therefore I need the date adapter.

```
const chartJSNodeCanvas = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({
    width: 512,
    height: 400,
    backgroundColour: "white",
    plugins: {
      modern: ['chartjs-plugin-annotation'],
      globalVariableLegacy: ["chartjs-adapter-date-fns"],
    },
  });
const image = await chartJSNodeCanvas.renderToBuffer(config);
fs.writeFileSync("c:/wswin/mychart.png", image);
```

then I get the error:

```
error: HTMLCanvasElement is not defined HTMLCanvasElement is not defined 
{"stack":"ReferenceError: HTMLCanvasElement is not defined\n    
at isImageOrCanvas (C:\\Users\\baumanng\\Documents\\Visual Studio Code\\wetterstation\\node_modules\\chartjs-plugin-annotation\\dist\\chartjs-plugin-annotation.js:334:57)\n
....
```

If I comment the plugin out

```
//modern: ['chartjs-plugin-annotation'],
```

then it is working, but the annotations are not visible.
On the local browser the config data is ok with annotations.

the packages are installed:

```
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "chartjs-adapter-date-fns": "^1.1.0-beta.1",
    "chartjs-node-canvas": "^4.1.6",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^1.3.1",
```

Where is my mistake?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved in version 1.4.0 of the annotation plugin. So you just need to update to fix it